# i would like to migrate my question from physics.se to here

Tags: support, migration

Recently i  asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68571/why-cant-you-use-your-cellphone-on-an-airplane) question at physics.se , and as per their comments over there i would like to migrate my question from there to here, whats the process evolved here, i would like to hear it from electronics.se for my question ,i posted an meta question over there too, and what were the procedures to migrate my question over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to migrate a question, flag it for moderator attention with a custom message: "Could you migrate this to [EE.SE] if it's more appropriate there?"

Comment: i done it already . and in meta one of the moderators commented it depends upon ee.se, http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/why-my-question-over-here-considered-as-off-topic/4435?noredirect=1#comment11478_4435, i would like to ask ee.se for migration so posted it over here

Comment: @Lonelybaby In that case just wait for it to happen :) when you want to migrate from X to Y, you have to ask X for this to happen. You can see the status of your flags here: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/25523/ (or on your profile page, click on the number next to "Helpful flags")

Comment: ok i ll wait for it just to bring attention i posted it over here , thanks for reply

Answer (score 3):

I did get a message from a Physics moderator to review your question for migration. I've decided to not migrate the question because it's borderline off-topic/not-constructive, and the skeptics answer has a pretty good treatment of the subject.